# Two Questions on MixedModels package in Julia

Tags: julia, mixed-models

EDITED: This is my first time posting and also using Julia so please forgive any mistakes I make in either and feel free to offer criticism where due.

<s>1) I am getting an error when I make a call like</s>

```
fit!(glmm(total_crashes ~ job_density + pop_density + (1|f), dat, Poisson()))
```

for any of the distributions.  The error is:

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("length(wts) must be 0 or length(y)")
in MixedModels.LinearMixedModel{T<:AbstractFloat}(::DataFrames.Formula, ::Array{String,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Union{MixedModels.Identity{Float64},MixedModels.MaskedLowerTri{Float64},UniformScaling{Float64}},1}, ::Array{Float64,1}) at /Users/ilan/.julia/v0.5/MixedModels/src/pls.jl:51
in #lmm#30(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Function, ::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at /Users/ilan/.julia/v0.5/MixedModels/src/pls.jl:136
in (::MixedModels.#kw##lmm)(::Array{Any,1}, ::MixedModels.#lmm, ::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame) at ./<missing>:0
in #glmm#63(::Array{Any,1}, ::Array{Any,1}, ::Function, ::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Distributions.Poisson{Float64}, ::GLM.LogLink) at /Users/ilan/.julia/v0.5/MixedModels/src/PIRLS.jl:47
in glmm(::DataFrames.Formula, ::DataFrames.DataFrame, ::Distributions.Poisson{Float64}) at /Users/ilan/.julia/v0.5/MixedModels/src/PIRLS.jl:64
```

However the documentation seems to say that weights defaults to 0.  What am I missing here?

2) <s>In any case,</s> the distribution I'm really looking for is Negative Binomial - does MixedModels support that yet and if so, what is the right code for it?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm ok on the first part, actually I'm really just curious if this package has Negative Binomial - I haven't been able to find anything to suggest it does.

Comment: Couple of pointers. Try to give a reproducible example in your question so that, ideally, someone can copy it and check if they can run it themselves. Also try to limit posts to a single question.

Comment: What is `f` ? Can you add a sample record from the DataFrame, or at least a couple of sample records with the relevant field.

Comment: I'd say you are pretty unlikely to get an answer on stackoverflow lest you heed the good advice in the above comments.